# Getting an 'out of memory' exception in this relatively simple program

Tags: c#, .net, image, io, out-of-memory

Here's my Picture.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace SharpLibrary_MediaManager
{
    public class Picture:BaseFile
    {
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public Image Thumbnail { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets file information of an image from a given image in the file path.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">File path of the image.</param>
        public override void  getFileInformation(string filePath)
        {
            FileInfo fileInformation = new FileInfo(filePath);
            if (fileInformation.Exists)
            {
                Name = fileInformation.Name;
                FileType = fileInformation.Extension;
                Size = fileInformation.Length;
                CreationDate = fileInformation.CreationTime;
                ModificationDate = fileInformation.LastWriteTime;
                Height = calculatePictureHeight(filePath);
                Width = calculatePictureWidth(filePath);                
            }
        }

        public override void getThumbnail(string filePath)
        {            
            Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
            Thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(40, 40, null, new IntPtr());            
        }

        private int calculatePictureHeight(string filePath)
        {
            var image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
            return image.Height;
        }

        private int calculatePictureWidth(string filePath)
        {
            var image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
            return image.Width;
        }
    }
}
```

And here, I'm using that class to pull information from every file in a given folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace SharpLibrary_MediaManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string folderPath = @"D:\Images\PictureFolder";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            List<Picture> lol = new List<Picture>();
            foreach (FileInfo x in folder.GetFiles())
            {
                Picture picture = new Picture();
                picture.getFileInformation(x.FullName);
                lol.Add(picture);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(lol[0].Name);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an Out Of Memory exception and I don't really know why. This is the first time I'm doing something like this so I'm pretty new to batch file processing, etc.

Any help guys? :)

**Edit:**
I opened the Task Manager to see memory usage and when I press the Button to run the method I notice my memory usage increases by 100mb~ every second.

**Edit 2:**
In my folder I have about 103 images, each image being ~100kb.
I need a solution where it doesn't matter how many images are in a folder. Someone recommended opening an image, doing my magic, then close it. I don't really understand what he meant by 'close'.

Can someone recommend a different approach? :)

**Edit 3:**
Still getting the out of memory exception, I've changed the code in Picture.cs based on recommendations, but I'm out of ideas. Any help?

```
public override void  getFileInformation(string filePath)
        {
            FileInfo fileInformation = new FileInfo(filePath);

            using (var image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
            {
                if (fileInformation.Exists)
                {
                    Name = fileInformation.Name;
                    FileType = fileInformation.Extension;
                    Size = fileInformation.Length;
                    CreationDate = fileInformation.CreationTime;
                    ModificationDate = fileInformation.LastWriteTime;
                    Height = image.Height;
                    Width = image.Width;
                }
            }
        }
```

Also, should I open a new question now that this one has grown a bit?

Comment: Can you give us a stack trace of the OOM exception?

Comment: How can I find that so I provide it?

Comment: An thrown exception has a stack trace, but never mind that, the problem is already spotted in your calculatePictureHeight and calculatePictureWidth methods.

Comment: Can you tell us when exactly your program crashes?  It would be helpful for us to know the exact place in your code where the problem occurs. (And don't forget to implement the `IDisposable` interface on your `Picture` class, as it holds an `Image` object.)

Comment: Please try to post a stack trace. Hell, post a screenshot of it if necessary (as long as it shows enough information). It's tricky to debug this without know precisely what operation causes it to run out of memory.

Comment: Have you considered using the profiler in Visual Studio or the CLRProfiler (http://http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979205.aspx) to understand the objects that are getting allocated and why?

Comment: Also, just because your image on disk is only 103K does not mean that is what it consumes in memory.  On disk, your images are probably compressed somewhat.  What are the dimensions of the images?  I think when loaded in the Image object, they are no longer compressed.

Comment: As a note, we have almost similiar issue, but image size were very small. If you try to get thumbnail with 0 height it will throw OutOfMemory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not calling Dispose on your Image instances. Also create your image once and then extract your data.

See also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z.aspx

**EDIT**
If copied your code and tested it with my Picture Library. My avg. FileSize is 2-3 MB per File. I've executed your program and it did exactly what it should. The GC did exactly what I've expected.

Memory of your Program was always about 11-35 MB Private Working set, Commit Size was stable at 43 MB.

I've aborted the program after 1156 files with a total picture size of 2.9 GB.

**So there must be another reason for you out of memory exception.**

Here's my program output and code:

```
1133: Total Size = 2.842,11 MB
1134: Total Size = 2.844,88 MB
1135: Total Size = 2.847,56 MB
1136: Total Size = 2.850,21 MB
1137: Total Size = 2.853,09 MB
1138: Total Size = 2.855,86 MB
1139: Total Size = 2.858,59 MB
1140: Total Size = 2.861,26 MB
1141: Total Size = 2.863,65 MB
1142: Total Size = 2.866,15 MB
1143: Total Size = 2.868,52 MB
1144: Total Size = 2.870,93 MB
1145: Total Size = 2.873,64 MB
1146: Total Size = 2.876,15 MB
1147: Total Size = 2.878,84 MB
1148: Total Size = 2.881,92 MB
1149: Total Size = 2.885,02 MB
1150: Total Size = 2.887,78 MB
1151: Total Size = 2.890,57 MB
1152: Total Size = 2.893,55 MB
1153: Total Size = 2.896,32 MB
1154: Total Size = 2.898,92 MB
1155: Total Size = 2.901,48 MB
1156: Total Size = 2.904,02 MB
```

Sourcecode:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace SharpLibrary_MediaManager
{
    public abstract class BaseFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        public long Size { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }

        public abstract void getFileInformation(string filePath);

    }


    public class Picture : BaseFile
    {
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public Image Thumbnail { get; set; }

        public override void getFileInformation(string filePath)
        {
            FileInfo fileInformation = new FileInfo(filePath);

            using (var image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
            {
                if (fileInformation.Exists)
                {
                    Name = fileInformation.Name;
                    FileType = fileInformation.Extension;
                    Size = fileInformation.Length;
                    CreationDate = fileInformation.CreationTime;
                    ModificationDate = fileInformation.LastWriteTime;
                    Height = image.Height;
                    Width = image.Width;
                    Thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(40, 40, null, new IntPtr());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string folderPath = @"C:\Users\arthur\Pictures";

            DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            List<Picture> lol = new List<Picture>();
            double totalFileSize = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (FileInfo x in folder.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                Picture p = new Picture();
                p.getFileInformation(x.FullName);
                lol.Add(p);
                totalFileSize += p.Size;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: Total Size = {1:n2} MB", ++counter, totalFileSize / 1048576.0);
            }

            foreach (var p in lol)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}x{2} px", p.Name, p.Width, p.Height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to free the resources used when opening an `Image` object.

Either you can call Dispose, or create your image in a `Using` statement

e.g.

```
public override void getThumbnail(string filePath)
{
    using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
    {
        Thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(40, 40, null, new IntPtr());
    }
}
```

And as your class contains an `Image` you should implement the `IDisposable` interface, so you can also use it in a `using` statement.

Comment: I don't see the `using` statement getting used very often. Is it just that it's not well known?

Comment: I use it everywhere I can (i.e. when the target class is `IDisposable`, and my program flow allows it).  You don't have to play with `Dispose`, and you are sure that your memory management is correctly performed.

Answer (score 5):

A few problems I see off the bat.  Firstly, you are loading each Image twice with your subsequent calls to CalculatePictureWidth and CalculatePictureHeight.  Secondly, you're never actually doing anything with the thumbnail, it appears.  Thirdly, you should call Dispose on the Image instances once you are done gathering information from them.

Comment: Well, without seeing the StackTrace of the Out Of Memory exception (when the exception breaks into the IDE, you should be able to click on the CallStack Window (Debug->Windows->CallStack), the only other thing I notice is that you are Getting the FileInfo, looping through each File, passing the Name to another function and then getting the same FileInfo again.  That could be streamlined, but I don't expect it's causing your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The Image file contains a handle to a large block of unmanaged data. This data has to be removed and you do this by explicitly calling Image.Dispose. Because you don't call Dispose in the calculatePictureHeight and calculatePictureWidth methods, the Image files are kept in memory, which is causing your OOM exceptions.

[Update]:
Perhaps I little more background is useful, why this is actually happening. After all, isn't there the GC to clean up this mess for us? Yes there is, and the GC is pretty effective. It will eventually also clean up objects, that we had to dispose.

The Image class contains a finalizer. This finalizer will ensure that all resources are cleared, even when you forget to call Dispose. However, what happens here is that you run out of memory, which immediately triggers a GC.Collect. During this collect, the GC finds all your unreferenced Images. However, because the GC will not run the finalizer method immediately, all your objects are promoted to Gen1 (they are kept in memory) and so are all your resources (the native memory). So even after the GC has kicked in, there is still too little memory and you get an OOM exception.

This is why you should always dispose objects that implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 2):

You should not store all images in a single list, you should do what you have with one picture at a time and dispose each picture after each iteration.

Check for Image.Dispose() method.

Comment: How can I dispose an instanced class?

Comment: you could use a using statement, like using(Picture p = new Picture()) { //do work here } then the dispose method is being called at the end of the brackets, or you could simple call the Dispose() method of the Picture.

Answer (score 1):

How many pictures do you have in that folder. I see you looping through all the pictures and loading them into memory directly and storing them in a list. It may be the cause.

Comment: It looks like what he's trying to do, at least, is loop through them, get height, width, and thumbnails, and just store those.  So each actual picture should only be in memory while those are being calculated.

Answer (score 1):

How big are your picture files?  How much files are in your directory?
Depending on those parameters I could see how you could get an OutOfMemory.  You may want to recheck your approach.  Instead of loading everything into memory, you should load each picture individually, perform your action and then continue (after you disposed your previous picture, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at your images one at a time. I have found certain .jpg's cause this - the image manipulating libraries have problems with certain images, not sure why. But we have had certain .jpg's saved from photoshop some odd way cause this. I'll bet you'll find it's one bad apple.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
public class Picture:BaseFile
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public Image Thumbnail { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets file information of an image from a given image in the file path.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePath">File path of the image.</param>
    public override void  getFileInformation(string filePath)
    {
        FileInfo fileInformation = new FileInfo(filePath);
        if (fileInformation.Exists)
        {
            /*
            Name, FileType, Size, etc
            */
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
            {
                Height = image.Height;
                Width = image.Width;
                Thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(40, 40, new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), default(IntPtr));
            }
        }
    }

    public bool ThumbnailCallback()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is:

If you call the GetThumbnailImage with one of the width or height arguments being -1, it will throw an OutOfMemoryException as well.

or

If you create an Image object by using Image.FromStream (for example a MemoryStream) and then close the stream (the MSDN says clear not to do that for the lifetime of the object) then calling this method (GetThumbnailImage) on the object will throw an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score -1):

Several people have mentioned calling dispose once done with the images. However, this is not enough and something the .net framework will do for you as memory usage increases. Since you've added each picture to a linked list the .NET framework can't dispose of it, as you implicitly keep a reference.

This means that all data stored within the picture class is kept during the foreach loop. From the code fragment I can't see what it is, it may include a compressed or even an uncompressed version of the images which could explain your memory explosion.

[Edit] removed part of anwer which others have pointed out to be irrelevant; I assumed picture class to be the XNA picture class.

Comment: I'm not using XNA, my class is just called Picture.

Comment: The pictures I refered to when I talked about disposing them were the actual pictures, not the thumbnails.  So I think (but I must be mistaken) that no reference is kept and thus that disposing them will be sufficent.  The only ones that will be kept are the thumbnails ones, and that's why I adviced him to implement `IDisposable` in his `Picture` class.

Comment: the framework will call the finalise when garbage collecting however he keeps a reference to the image so it will never be collected

Comment: Which image are you talking about ?

Comment: public Image Thumbnail { get; set; } in the picture class

Comment: Brian, that's not the same image he loads, this one is a smaller one he created from the loaded image.  That's why I adviced him to implement `IDisposable` on his class, and in the `Dispose` method, he should simply dispose the "thumbnail" image.